# how do make this show/hide more concise?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

There are many show/hide questions and examples but I can't find the answer.

I have a simple code like this which  is used in a few areas within a page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#mini-cart').hide(); 
    jQuery('#mini-cart-a').click(function ()  { 
        jQuery('#mini-cart').toggle(400);  
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Each show/hide uses its own ID, so I simply group ids like so:

```
jQuery('#show-hide1, #show-hide2').hide();
```

Problem with this method is, when I click on of the show/hid element, all of the elements show.

So I tried something like this but only the first ones works, the second ones isn't working, when I click on it, it does nothing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('show-hide1, #show-hide2').hide();
    jQuery('show-hide1 a, #show-hide2 a').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next().toogle(400);
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```

There are 4 different areas that I need the show/hide within a page and  really don't want to repeat the same codes 4 times. Thanks!

**Update:**
(Sorry I can't use the Add Comment nor answer my question)

Thank you all, for your helpful reply.

Lee's version is more like a tabs - I don't want the hidden div associate an ID to anchor tag. It's CMS enviornment so I try to make it simpler if possible.

Andy's version has similar ID issue, so I opted in for roXon's

RoXon: 
http://jsbin.com/ihoqi3/2/
Click on View Bag (2), you can see it's working, however if you go to Questions' tab, click on "Ask a question", it opens up the hidden container from View Bag.

Jeremy B's version:
http://jsbin.com/ibayu4
It hides the toggleLink's text.

From the example page, the "Choose your tea" and "Write a Review" in the Reviews Tab require similar treatment, but if I can get the above mentioned two working, the rest will take care by itself :)

Right now I use 4 separate codes to make it work.

p/s, I need to use the herf anchor because this is important for keyboard user, with the JS show/hide the hidden div can't be toggled.

Comment: can you provide the html structure

Comment: This is incorrect: `jQuery('show-hide1 a, #show-hide2 a').click(function () {` you forgot to add a `#` in front of `show-hide1` ! :)

Comment: A typo mistake. In the site it's correct and it opens up all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a class such as ".tab" and the id of the div containing the content that you want to display for the particular ".tab"
i.e.

```
$(".tab").click(function(){
   var clickedID = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
   $("#" + clickedID).toggle();
});

<div class="tab container1"></div>
<div id="container1">This container will be displayed if you click on the div .tab container 1</div>

<div class="tab container2"></div>
<div id="container2">This container will be displayed if you click on the div .tab container 2</div>
```

Comment: Hi PieterG, thanks, this does work. My test shows that the ID (e.g. #container1) must match the .container1 class for it to work. In CMS environment (this is pretty much web developers use these days), it may not be so flexible. Could it be possible for the '.tab' to trigger the '#container1'?

Answer (score 2):

Made a little example of how you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ytx2J/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggleLink" data-id="1">1</a> 
<a href="#" class="toggleLink" data-id="2">2</a> 
<a href="#" class="toggleLink" data-id="3">3</a>
<a href="#" class="toggleLink" data-id="4">4</a>

<div id="show-hide1">div 1</div>
<div id="show-hide2">div 2</div>
<div id="show-hide3">div 3</div>
<div id="show-hide4">div 4</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggleLink').click(function(ev){
       $('#show-hide'+$(this).data('id')).toggle(400); 
       ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

start by giving each of the areas the same class.

```
jQuery('.hider').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

This will cause only the "hider" you clicked on to toggle. Each one will work independently.

Comment: but from his code it looks like he wants to toggle the element from a different a, not by clicking the element itself

Answer (score 0):

Like Andy's but slightly different, to allow a different structure of ID's

#### HTML

```
<a href="#div1" class="toggleLink">1</a> 
<a href="#div2" class="toggleLink">2</a> 
<a href="#div3" class="toggleLink">3</a>
<a href="#div4" class="toggleLink">4</a>

<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
<div id="div3">div 3</div>
<div id="div4">div 4</div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggleLink').click(function(ev){
       $($(this).attr('href')).toggle(400); 
       ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grttn/)

Comment: please see my reply added in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andy's but slightly different, to allow remove ID's as not necessary.
We can keep it simple right?

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ytx2J/2/)

```
<a href="#" class="toggleLink">1</a>
<a href="#" class="toggleLink">2</a>
<a href="#" class="toggleLink">3</a>
<a href="#" class="toggleLink">4</a>

<div class="show-hide">div 1</div>
<div class="show-hide">div 2</div>
<div class="show-hide">div 3</div>
<div class="show-hide">div 4</div>
```

```
$('.toggleLink').click(function(){
    $('.show-hide:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').toggle(400);
});
```

It's a nice combination on pointing an `index` anchor to a `:eq()` element --> as both '0' based.

Comment: problem is, he said that there are 4 different areas on the page he wants to toggle, so the divs probably won't be in any particular order. I'm not saying it wouldn't work though :)